# Rename uploaded user image Google Cloud

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, image-uploading

I have the images uploading to google cloud, however I am not able to rename them to a random string before the image is uploaded.

I am wondering if anyone has a solution to this please.

Code:

```
<?php
# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/PATH TO JSON');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);

   $storage = new StorageClient([
      'projectId' => 'XXXXXXXXXX'
  ]);


   $bucket = $storage->bucket('abcd');

// Upload a file to the bucket.
$bucket->upload(
    fopen('./test.jpg', 'r') // I WANT TO RENAME THIS FILE BEING UPLOADED AND YES i UNDERSTAND IT WILL BE A $_FILE TYPE WHEN I FINISH THE CODE.
);



// Download and store an object from the bucket locally.
$object = $bucket->object('test.jpg');
$object->downloadToFile('/cache/test2.jpg');


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the answer is really easy, first you need to read the file that you want to upload. second you will want to generate your new filename, for this i used two user properties (these will most likely stay the same or change very rarely). I also used the timestamp of the request. My theory is no two people should have the same personal information (IP address & user agent) [I will add the users UID once i have finished the prototype.

If anyone else would like the code please see below, and please improve it & share the changes you would make (be great to see what we all come up with.

> THIS IS FREE TO USE AND NO NEED TO GIVE CREDIT

```
$new_file_name     =   md5(time().md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
    $path = "./test.jpg";
    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $current = file_get_contents('./test.jpg');
    $rand = $new_file_name.".".$ext;
    echo $rand;
    file_put_contents("./cache/".$rand, $current);

// Upload a file to the bucket.
$bucket->upload(
    fopen('./cache/'.$rand, 'r')
);
```

The only problem with it is that you are left with the new files in cache folder but you can add a delete function after the file has been uploaded.

**Full code on github**

[OFFICIAL GITHUB REPO](https://github.com/redimongo/Google_Storage_Upload_Rename)